# Web Query from URL in Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I believe I have thoroughly researched this question (sorry if you have seen the answer, please be patient with me).

Truly a newcomer to VBA/Macros and do not even fully understand where to "put" the codes that are provided in these message boards, that is why I prefer a formula.

My sheet has cells which feed to a hyperlink (i.e. A1=JFK, B1:CVG, C1=HYPERLINK("http://www.gcmap.com/dist?p="&A1&"-"&B1,"My Flight").

If you visit the link (http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=jfk-cvg) it shows the flying distance between these two points - 589 mi.

What I am trying to do is do a web query in Excel based off the link provided in cell C1, and then have the web query point to the total distance included in the link - and then populate another cell on my sheet (D1) with that distance.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to enter a macro into VBA? If so, check out my answer below - I think this does what you're looking for.  If you're not sure, [here's a website](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) that shows you how to add it.

Comment: any word on whether the below works?

Comment: Unfortunately haven't had a second to work on it - but alas, here I am!
I will be testing it this afternoon - TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's something like this:

```
 Sub getMiles()
 'Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975506/how-to-download-source-code-from-a-website-with-vba for idea
Dim k As Long, s
Dim URL2          As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
URL2 = ws.Cells(1, 3) 'Cell C1 is the URL

' to get data from the url we need to creat a win Http object_
' tools > references > select Windows Win Http Services 5.1
Dim Http2         As New WinHttpRequest
'open the url
Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False

' send request
Http2.Send
'MsgBox Http2.ResponseText
Debug.Print s
'Debug.Print Http2
Debug.Print URL2
Dim Resp          As String: Resp = Http2.ResponseText
Dim Lines2        As Variant: Lines2 = Split(Resp, ">")

Worksheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set newWS = ActiveSheet
newWS.Name = "Temp for source code"

k = 0
For k = LBound(Lines2) To UBound(Lines2)
    newWS.Cells(1 + k, 1).Value = Lines2(k)
    k = k + 1
Next k



Dim findString As String, stringCell As Range
findString = "&nbsp;mi"
Set stringCell = newWS.Columns(1).Find(what:=findString)

Dim milesFlown    As String
milesFlown = Left(stringCell.Value, WorksheetFunction.Search("&", stringCell, 1) - 1)

'MsgBox ("You would fly " & milesFlown)
ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = milesFlown

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
newWS.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It's sort of roundabout, but what it does is get the source code of your URL, and in that source code, look for a string that only seems to occur before the miles are given (" mi"), then finds the numbers to the left of the &, and sets that as your miles.  You will need to tweak the macro to correctly point to the cell with your URL. Let me know if you need any help doing so!

edit: Ah, to use this code, with Excel open, press ALT+F11, this will open up the VB editor.  I think you can insert this code (just copy/paste) into the "Sheet1 (Sheet1)" part.  If not, you'll need to right click "VBAProject ([yourbook])" and Insert Module, and put the code there.  It should then show up in your macro list (View tab --> Macros).

Edit2: Also, you'll need to add a Reference most likely in VBA.  Press ALT+F1 to open VB Editor, then in Tools -> References, look for "Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1" and add a check mark, and click "Ok" to add this reference.  Otherwise, you'll get an error.

Edit3: Updated the code.  It now puts the source code on a new sheet, so anything you have in Col. A won't be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your work on my problem.

I followed your instructions meticulously and copied and pasted the infoprmation as isntruced - ticked off the WinHTTP box as instructed, and when I went to run the macro, Excel's dialogue box returned "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

I entered debug mode (where I am out of my depths) and the first item highlighted was :
Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False

I also tried to change the line:
URL2 = ws.Cells(1, 3) 'Cell C1 is the URL 
By replacing "'Cell C1 is the URL" with "'Cell A12 is the URL"

As always - TIA

Comment: Did you add the reference to VB? If "Microsoft WinHTTP Services,..." isn't in the list, hit "Browse", and search for "winhttp.dll" and open that one.

Comment: On the above example of my attempts, yes I had. But because I was not sure that I was correctly changing the variable cell (by simply dictating "Cell A12 is the URL"), I tried on a sheet where I had the URL in C1 already. This time I checked through all of the steps as prior mentioned (again ticking off the Microsoft WinHTTP Services) as instructed and the dialogue box reads: "Run-time error '-2147012890 (80072ee6)': The URL does not use a recognized protocol". When entering debug mode, the item highlighted was again "Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False". Sorry i am so awful with this, thanks again